# Matlab random number rng: choosing a seed

Tags: matlab, random, random-seed

I would like to know more precisely what happends when you choose a custom seed in Matlab, e.g.:

```
rng(101)
```

From my (limited, nut nevertheless existing) understanding of how pseudo-random number generators work, one can see the seed conceptually as **choosing a position** in a "**very long list of pseudo-random numbers**".

Question: lets say, (in my Matlab script), I choose rng(100) for my first computation (a sequence of instructions) and then rng(1e6) for my second. Please, note that each time I do some computations it involves generating up to about 300k random numbers (each time).

-> Does that imply that I make sure there is no overlap between the sequence in the "list" starting at 100 and ending around 300k and the one starting at 1e6 and ending at 1'300'000 ? (the idead of "no overlap" comes from the fact since the rng(100) and rng(1e6) are separated by much more than 300k)

i.e. that these are 2 "independent" sequences, (as far as I remember this 'long list' would be generated by a special PRNG algorithm, most likely involing modular arithmetic..?)

Comment: Better not set a seed at all. MATLAB always starts with the same sequence, but if you run your two computations in the same MATLAB session, the second one will use a random number sequence starting off where the first one stopped, and so will guaranteed to be different and independent. Unless you need to ensure identical random number sequences, don't use a seed at all.

Comment: I will not use the same session . They are scripts that will be run separately (mayb with nohup nodesktop nosplash etc) in the background and an unkown time.

Comment: Then you probably want to use `rng shuffle` instead. Using that it is more or less impossible to get the same sequence twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not the case. The mapping between the seed and the "position" in our list of generated numbers is not linear, you could actually interpret it as a hash/one way function. It could actually happen that we get the same sequence of numbers shifted by one position (but it is very unlikely).

By default, MATLAB uses the [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) [(source)](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how would you "maximize" the probability not to get the same, or a similar/overlapping sequence?

Comment: @Machupicchu By not choosing the same seed twice. If anything else was possible, it wouldn't be as random as it is. It has a period of `2^19937-1` which is more than `10^6000`, and which also means that for most purposes you shouldn't worry about the chance of having two times the same sequence, even if you sample sequences of  `300k`  values. If you need even "better" randomness check out https://www.random.org/ or try to find a cryptographically secure random number generator, but by definition these are a lot slower.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite.  The seed you give to `rng` is the initiation point for the Mersenne Twister algorithm (by default) that is used to generate the pseudorandom numbers.  If you choose two different seeds (no matter their relative non-negative integer values, except for maybe a special case or two), you will have effectively independent pseudorandom number streams.

For "99%" of people, the major uses of seeding the rng are using the 'shuffle' argument (to use a non-default seed based on the time to help ensure independence of numbers generated across multiple sessions), or to give it one particular seed (to be able to reproduce the same pseudorandom stream at a later date). If you try to finesse the seeds further without being extremely careful, you are more likely to cause issues than do anything helpful.

`RandStream` can be used to break off separate streams of pseudorandom numbers if that really matters for your application (it likely doesn't).